# Howto get a list of (sound) resource names in a Resource DLL

Tags: c++, windows

I have a resource DLL that contains a bunch of small sounds.

After I have loaded the DLL, how can I get a list of the names of these sounds?

I'm using

```
HMODULE handle              = LoadLibraryA("atResources");
```

to load the DLL, and I can find a resource that I know the name of by

```
HRSRC hResInfo = ::FindResourceA(modHandle, resName.c_str(), MAKEINTRESOURCE(10));
```

But how to get a list of all resources, in case I don't know the names?

Comment: You are likely looking for `EnumResourceTypes[Ex]` and `EnumResourceNames[Ex]`

Comment: I'll look into those functions!